# Decent webcam for conference room

Tags: webcam

I need a decent webcam for a conf room that seats 30 people.  I'm okay with a wide-angle camera. I've also heard that cameras exist that will automatically find and focus on the person speaking, but my google searches haven't provided any results.  There's a media PC near where I want to mount this, so USB-only is acceptable. If not I can do wireless or ethernet, preferably PoE.  Planning on using MSN or Skype, so don't really need anything fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is for a conference room I suggest **Microsoft LifeCam Cinema** . But it is little bit costly

**Key features include**

> - 720p HD widescreen
> - Auto Focus
> - High-precision glass element lens
> - ClearFrame Technology
> - Digital Microphone
> - TrueColor Technology

For more Information go to http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/digitalcommunication/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=008